# Express-handlebars route parameters to link to the same page

Tags: javascript, express-handlebars

I have an SPA made with express-handlebars.
I need to pass route parameters in the URL so I can pick it up in the subsequent page it leads to and render the details pertaining to that parameter.
for eg.

`www.sitename.com/events/1` , `www.sitename.com/events/2`
1 and 2 will be the event IDs which I will then use to fetch the details of that event.

I need handlebars to render the same `eventdetail` page for me for both routes as shown above. But it seems to break everything, and the console check showed me that it was trying to go inside a "events" folder and then trying to find all the files within and eventually throwing a 404 page as well.

These are the routes I have right now in my routes.js page.

```
router.get("/events", function(req, res, next) {
  res.render("events");
});
router.get("/eventdetail", function(req, res, next) {
  res.render("eventdetail");
});
```

How do I go about with this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your routes to handle path param passed in url. Currently, express is looking for path which matches `events/1` which is not exists in you configuration hence it's throwing 404 error.

Change your `/events` route to use path param like below

````
router.get("/events/:page", function(req, res, next) {
    // you can access page value here with 
    // req.params.page
    // for /events/1, req.params.page will return value "1"
    res.render("events");
});```
````

Comment: I did try this before I posted here, but this lead to the entire website breaking because now the server would try to look for all dependencies (all js and css files) in `www.sitename/events/1` folder structure. Anyway, i passed the event id as a parameter in the url (www.sitename.com/eventdetail?id=1) cause that seemed to be the simplest, least complicated way of doing it.